# Creating hover and click conditions in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.tag12 span {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: #D0E8E4;
    border-radius: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
</style>

<div class="tag12"><span> Click here for more information. </span></div>

</html>
```

I am looking to change the color when this is element is hovered, and go to an external site when it is clicked. For the hover, I have tried doing `.tag12:hover{}`, and `.tag12 span:hover{}` within the style brackets but neither of these have changed the color on hover.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.tag12 span {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: #D0E8E4;
    border-radius: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
.tag12 a:hover{
    color:red;
    }
</style>

<div class="tag12"><span><a href="">Click here for more information.</a></span></div>

</html>
```

To remove the underline globally.

```
a:link{
      text-decoration: none;
      }
```

or for the class

```
.tag12 a:link{
      text-decoration: none;
      }
```

Change the whole element

```
.tag12 span:hover{
      background-color:green;
      }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I also inserted `background: blue` in the hover section, but I noticed it's only highlighting the text on hover. Would you know how to make the whole element turn a different color when it's hovered?

Comment: @youewew you need to use background: color; to set the whole background color

Comment: added the answer above

Comment: Thanks! This is gold!

Comment: no problem please tick as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

just read more about [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), so you can achieve your aim,
anyway here is a snippet to show up how to change element style in hover,

also read more about  [href attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) to learn how to create links

goodluck.

```css
.tag12 span {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: #D0E8E4;
    border-radius: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}

.tag12 span:hover {
color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag12"><a href="#"><span> Click here for more information. </span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check something like this
You can read more about available style options and the CSS selector on [w3shool](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) its a great source for beginners, Happy read :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.tag12 span {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: #D0E8E4;
    border-radius: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
/* Use somthing like this to change style of hover element itself*/
.tag12:hover{
background-color:blue;
}
/* Use somthing like this to change style of siblings on hover on parent*/
.tag12:hover a{ 
color:red;
}
</style>
<!-- to redirect user to another page on click you can use a tag insted of span and replace # in href with target url -->
<div class="tag12"><a href="#"> Click here for more information. </a></div>

</html>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!